# Add javadoc and sources to eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to add javadoc and sources to group of jars with one action. Suppose I want to add spring javadoc and sources to all my spring jars at classpath? Adding javadoc to each jar separately will take long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manage your project's dependencies with something like Maven or Gradle, you can have it download any available sources and/or javadocs, and create an Eclipse .classpath for you. See for example the documentation for maven-eclipse-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/attach-library-sources.html. Once you set up your pom.xml file (which is non-trivial), then you just run "mvn eclipse".

Note that the Maven plugin "maven-eclipse-plugin" differs from the Eclipse plugin "m2eclipse", though they serve a related purpose.

Comment: But what should I do if don't use maven?

Comment: If you have the jars and the javadocs, maybe you could manipulate the .classpath file directly with a little script? I don't know of a way to make Eclipse do it on its own